# Using annotation_map_tile in ggplot to add a basemap to a single point

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I'm trying to use annotate_map_tile() from ggplot2 to add a basemap to my ggplot maps. I've had success using it with geom_sf() layers, but it is throwing an error with a single point loaded through geom_point().

Here's the code:

```
site<- data.frame(longitude = -75.144353, latitude = 39.917631)

ggplot()+
  annotation_map_tile("cartolight")+
  geom_point(data = site, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), size = 5)
```

The error reads "Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_raster, x$raster, x$x, x$y, x$width, x$height,  :
cannot allocate memory block of size 67108864 Tb". Any help?

Comment: Hi. First of all, I think you should use `geom_spatial_point` instead of `geom_point` since you can control the CRS of the input object. Anyway, I think there are also bugs with `geom_spatial_point` as reported [here](https://github.com/paleolimbot/ggspatial/issues/60). Maybe you can add a comment to that GH issue explaining your problem (or create a new issue).

Answer (score 3):

If you convert your point to an `sf` object and then plot it using `geom_sf()` it seems to work just fine. One reason your code is failing is that `annotation_map_tile()` doesn't know which tiles to pull because you haven't specified any data for it.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(ggspatial)

site <- data.frame(longitude = -75.144353, latitude = 39.917631) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)

ggplot(site) +
  annotation_map_tile("cartolight") +
  geom_sf(size = 5)
```

[image]